# why did the adivce not work in my project based on Spring-framework?

Tags: java, spring, aop

I used it as follows:

```
@Component    
@Aspect    
public class RecordActivity {

@Pointcut("execution(public void test.article.service.ArticleService.*(..))")    
public void addArticle(){};

@Around("addArticle()")    
public void addActivity(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint){

        System.out.println("------add an article-------");
        try {
            writer.write(object.getObject());
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            bufferWriter.closeResource();
            ServiceUtil.outOfError(response,"error!!!");
            return;
        }
        bufferWriter.closeResource();
        try {
            joinPoint.proceed(params);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**Controller**

```
@Controller    
public class PublicHandler {

@RequestMapping("/addarticle")    
public void addArtcile( HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response,Article article){

    articleService.addArticle(article);
    ...
}
```

**Service**

```
@Service    
public class ArticleService {

    @Transactional(rollbackFor=Exception.class)
    public void addArticle(Article article){
             ...
             ...
   }
}
```

springDispatcherServlet-servlet.xml  contains:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="test.aop"></context:component-scan>

<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>

<mvc:annotation-driven  ></mvc:annotation-driven>
```

jar package contains:

```
aspectJ.1.7.4:
 aspectjrt.jar

 aspectjweaver.jar

com.springsource.org.aopalliance-1.0.0.jar

com.springsource.net.sf.cglib-2.2.0.jar

spring-aop-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar
```

it's a webApplication which runs in:
 server:  tomcat7.0.78

JDK:1.7

After configured above,it started normal,not throwing any exception. I visited the add-Article service by webbrowser and it fed back an normal result but the advice method did not be executed.
   what did I something wrong?

Comment: are the package names correct?

Comment: Where is the "advice method" ? Did you forget to post some code , or are you talking about the  "addActivity" method ?

Comment: @Jens package names are correct.

Comment: @nos yes!,I means the addActivity did not be executed.

Comment: Sorry!I make some confusing description.the "advice method" is the "addActivity" method

Comment: @Jens I have tested.the other class in the same package which contains  RecordActivity class was scanned,and one method in the other class was executed successfully

Comment: Try changing your pointcut to `@Pointcut("execution(public void test.article.service.ArticleService+.*(..))")`

Comment: @alfcope it still doesn't work.?-?,I have looking for solution for two days.I have read the documentation in spring:http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#aop-aj-ltw-environments.although I could not comprehend completely,I thought  the starting example  above has not  missed something.but it do not work.

Comment: Does your pointcut work removing all transactional annotations at your ArticleService service?

Comment: @ alfcope Thank you for your advice! your question reminded me the poxy mechnism. 
I tried to add the "@before" advice whose “@pointcut” execution point to a method in a "@Controll " bean, that has no "@Transactional" annotation.
I find some hint and the advice was executed.But I was confused that whether the bean 
which contains "Transactional" annotation have a proxy already or something others matters and
how Spring realize the others annotation, for instance "@Autowired"、
" @RequestMapping" and so on.

Comment: And I added <aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true" /> in the configuration XML.what does the " proxy-target-class" attribute impact? I thought that my ArticleService Class has no implemented interface,so the Aop was realized by the other way before.It turned out I was wrong.

Comment: Of course the transactional bean has a proxy. As your service does not implement an interface, you needs to use `proxy-target-class="true"` and that means Spring, at startup time, is creating a class extending your service. When you think you are calling your service you are not, what you are really invoking is this proxy sub class and it calls the target method. More info here: https://spring.io/blog/2012/05/23/transactions-caching-and-aop-understanding-proxy-usage-in-spring

Comment: Thank you very much! @alfcope  your instruction and the link are very useful to me!  And I  am grateful to everybody above for commenting this question.thanks again.