# why did the pointcut only triggers in @Controller bean but not work in other beans which have no @Controller annotation?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, aop

My configuration is the same as this question: [why did the adivce not work in my project based on Spring-framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44692648/why-did-the-adivce-not-work-in-my-project-based-on-spring-framework).

I found the reason why the pointcut did not be match was that the bean annotated `@Service` has the `@Transactional` annotation.

I tried to add a `@Pointcut` matching a method inside a `@Controller` bean and the corresponding method annotated `@Before` was invoked normally,using this pointcut. But when I tried to add `@Pointcut` matching a method inside a bean with no `@Controller` annotation,the corresponding method annotated `@Before` was not invoked.

The code and other situation was listed as follows:

**Aspect**

```
@Component
@Aspect
public class RecordActivity{
    @Pointcut("execution(void test.article.handler.PublicHandler.addArticle(..))")
    public void addControllArticle(){};

    @Pointcut("execution(void   test.article.serviceAspectWrap.ArticleServiceWrap.*(..))")
    public void addWrapArticle(){};

    @Pointcut("execution(public void test.article.service.ArticleService.*(..))")
    public void addServiceArticle(){};

    //this method was invoked normally
    @Before("addControllArticle()")
    public void addarticleActivity(){
        System.out.println("------add an Controllarticle-------");
    }

    //this method did not be invoked
    @Before("addWrapArticle()")
    public void addarticleActivity(){
        System.out.println("------add an Wraparticle-------");
    }

    //this method did not be invoked
    @Before("addSerivceArticle()")
    public void addarticleActivity(){
        System.out.println("------add an Servicearticle-------");
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
@Controller    
public class PublicHandler {

//this method was visited by webbrowser and could feed back a normal result.

@RequestMapping("/addarticle")
public void addArtcile( HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response,Article article){  


articleService.addArticle(article);
...
}
```

**Service**

```
@Service
public class ArticleService {

    //this method was visited by webbrowser and could feed back a normal result.
    @Transactional(rollbackFor=Exception.class)
    public void addArticle(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response,Article article){
                .....
    }
}
```

**ServiceWrap**

```
@Component
public class ArticleServiceWrap{
 @Autowired
     ArticleService articleService;`

     //this method was visited by webbrowser and could feed back a normal result.
     public void addArticle( HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response,Article article){
        articleService.addArticle(request, response, article);
    }
```

There is no package missed to be scanned.
It is very confusing to me. please tell me why.Thanks advance!

Comment: Something was missed.The “@controll” bean has a member:@Autowired ArticleServiceWrap articleService

Comment: Learn to format your code correctly before asking questions.

Comment: A subclass is created so you should use something like `@Pointcut("execution(public void test.article.service.ArticleService+.*(..))")`, notice the `+`.

Comment: ok,Thank you for your correction.I am not good at expressing in english.But I will improve it.

Comment: @M.Deinum  It doesn't work.The method annotated ' @Before("addControllArticle()")' was invoked normally ,which has no '+',meanwhile the '@Controller' bean with no implemented Interface.Is it right the '@Controller' bean has no implemented Interface in Spring ?

Comment: For the controller there is no proxy (initially) so it matches the regular class. Due to `@Transactional` there is a proxy created and on how your classes are structured (no interfaces) a subclass is created. The `+` means subclasses/implementations in the pointcut else it has to be an exact match. Your comment on implementing interfaces makes no sense as that makes only sense when your classes implement interfaces.

Comment: OK.Thank you for your help.

Comment: But the problem is still  not solved.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason.The test.aop package was scaned after the test.article.serviceAspectWrap.ArticleServiceWrap class have been scaned.I reversed them and the method annotated `@Before("addWrapArticle()")` was invoked.